# How to change data type in pyspark dataframe automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have data from csv file, and use it in jupyter notebook with pysaprk. I have many columns and all of them have string data type. I know how to change data type manually, but there is any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `inferSchema` option when you load your csv file, to let spark try to infer the schema. With the following example csv file, you can get two different schemas depending on whether you set `inferSchema` to true or not:

```
seq,date
1,13/10/1942
2,12/02/2013
3,01/02/1959
4,06/04/1939
5,23/10/2053
6,13/03/2059
7,10/12/1983
8,28/10/1952
9,07/04/2033
10,29/11/2035
```

Example code:

```
df = (spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "false") # default option
      .load(path))
df.printSchema()
df2 = (spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .load(path))
df2.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- seq: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)

root
 |-- seq: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define the schema before reading the file:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
  
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.show()
df.printSchema()

+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|    James|          |   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|
|  Michael|      Rose|        |40288|     M|  4000|
|   Robert|          |Williams|42114|     M|  4000|
|    Maria|      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|     |     F|    -1|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+

root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- middlename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: integer (nullable = true)
```